# Windows 10 file deleting from Explorer is very slow

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10

Ever since I went from Windows 7 to Windows 10, file deleting from Explorer has become very slow. For example, deleting my Steam folder with 180K files in it timed itself at 2 hours! And this wasn't moving stuff to the recycling bin, it was straight delete (hold down shift when clicking delete on file menu in Windows Explorer).

Yet, deleting the same folder from the command prompt using rmdir /s /q took a few seconds.

How can I speed up deleting from Explorer?

Comment: Instll the Windows Performance toolkit from Win10 SDK (https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and run the command (copy them into a .cmd and run it): http://pastebin.com/9R3Ehbs3

Comment: Having to install an SDK to fix slow deleting seems a bit ... excessive, wouldn't you say?

Comment: no, only this way I can see what happens on your system

Comment: I can confirm, that since I upgraded to windows 10 the disk access generally and deleting files also is extremely slow. I will likely downgrade who the hell knows what an indexing mess Microsoft made.